# How do I compile libgimp and create .so file?

Tags: c, rust, gimp

I am trying to create compile libgimp and generate `.so` file. What are the options I have?

```
gimptool-2.0 --build plugin.c
```

The above command just create executable. I would like to create `.so` file and need to use it in a Rust program.

Comment: **your question title is wrong.** see `man gimptool`. it has "environment" section, where you can see that you can set a `CFLAGS` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a prerequisite for a rust library you're trying to use?  You should probably just install the libgimp2.0-dev package for your system.

Answer (score -2):

For compile files using command prompt, you use g++ Hello.cpp after you do ./a.out to execute the file. Remember that when downloading the application, there should have been an option that was a link to the command prompt. only if you've selected that it would work.